# "This worker or driver is waiting to receive a class definition so that..."

Tags: tensorflow2.0, ray

Maybe this is a trivial problem, but I have gotten this message when executing Ray and tensorflow, and the script stops. How I can solve this problem?. The scripts is working ok until this message is received unexpectedly.

"WARNING worker.py:1619 -- This worker or driver is waiting to receive a class definition so that it can deserialize an object from the object store. This may be fine, or it may be a bug"

Comment: I am facing the same issue with ray and not using the tensorflow2